# Implententing a swipe view using a Fragment

Tags: android, swipe, android-tablayout, uiswipegesturerecognizer, swipe-gesture

I am designing a constitution app and I want to use a tabbed layout with swipe view. The tabs get data from the database using a custom adapter. Since the data size (no of fragment) is unknown, I want every swipe to generate a new view which are the different chapter content from the Constitution.

I want something that looks like the dictionary app below, with those swipe labels on both sides. I am familiar with tabs but I would love to get a resource to help me achieve this, since most documentation I have seen doesn't explain this. Thanks

[image]

Comment: look for viewpager

Comment: Its just a viewpager. You  can achieve your desired output with the help of view pager.

Answer (score 0):

Modify this with your desired OutPut

onCreate

```
 ArrayList<McqQuestionBean> mcqQuestionBeans= new ArrayList<McqQuestionBean>();
        adapter = new NewsFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),
                mcqQuestionBeans, MCQTestActivity.this);
        pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Base Adapter

```
public class NewsFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

private ArrayList<McqQuestionBean> mcqQuestionBeans;

private McqQuestionFragment fragment;
private Activity context;

public NewsFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, ArrayList<McqQuestionBean> mcqQuestionBeans, Activity context) {
    super(fm);
    this.mcqQuestionBeans = mcqQuestionBeans;

    this.context = context;

}

public void update(ArrayList<McqQuestionBean> mcqQuestionBeans) {
    this.mcqQuestionBeans = mcqQuestionBeans;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mcqQuestionBeans.size();
}

@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.getItemPosition(object);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    fragment = McqQuestionFragment.newInstance(mcqQuestionBeans.get(position), position, context);

    return fragment;

}

}
```

Your Fragment McqQuestionFragment

```
public class McqQuestionFragment extends Fragment {

private int position, porrefid;
    private String question;
    private ArrayList<McqQuestionChoiceBean> choices;   



@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        position = getArguments().getInt("position");
        porrefid = getArguments().getInt("porrefid");
        userMarkedOn = getArguments().getInt("userMarkedOn");
        question = getArguments().getString("question");
        choices = (ArrayList<McqQuestionChoiceBean>) getArguments()
                .getSerializable("choices");
    }

    public static McqQuestionFragment newInstance(
            McqQuestionBean mcqQuestionBean, int position, Activity activity) {
        final McqQuestionFragment f = new McqQuestionFragment();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString("question", mcqQuestionBean.getQuestion());
        args.putInt("position", position);
        args.putInt("userMarkedOn", mcqQuestionBean.getUserCorrectedOn());
        args.putSerializable("choices", mcqQuestionBean.getChoices());
        args.putInt("porrefid", mcqQuestionBean.getPorrefid());
        f.setArguments(args);

        return f;
    }

}
```